# MVC Model Binding a Complex Type to a Simple Type and Vice Versa

Tags: model-view-controller, model-binding

Here's a scenario:

I have an autocomplete plugin (custom) that keeps a hidden field of JSON objects (using a specific struct).

I've created an Html helper that helps me easily bind to a specific custom model (basically, it has a JSON property that is for two-way binding and a property that lets me deserialize the JSON into the appropriate struct):

```
public class AutoCompleteModel {
    public string JSON { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Person> People {
        get {
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Person>(this.JSON);
        }
        set {
            this.JSON = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(value);
        }
     }
 }
```

This works great and I can model bind using the default binder `@Html.Autocomplete(viewModel => viewModel.AutoCompleteModelTest)`. The HTML helper generates HTML like:

```
<input type="text" id="AutoCompleteModelTest_ac" name="AutoCompleteModelTest_ac" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="AutoCompleteModelTest_JSON" name="AutoCompleteModelTest.JSON" value="{JSON}" />
```

The problem is this is not the best way for consumers. They have to manually set the People property to an array of Person structs. In my data layer, my domain objects probably will not be storing the full struct, only the person's ID (a corporate ID). The autocomplete will take care of looking up the person itself if only given an ID.

The best scenario will be to call it like this:

`@Html.Autocomplete(domainObject => domainObject.PersonID)` or
`@Html.Autocomplete(domainObject => domainObject.ListOfPersonIDs`

I would like it to work against the string property AND against the custom AutoCompleteModel. The autocompleter only updates a single hidden field, and that field name is passed back on postback (the value looks like: `[{ "Id":"12345", "FullName":"A Name"},{ "Id":"12347", "FullName":"Another Name" }]`).

The problem is, of course, that those domain object properties only have an ID or array of IDs, not a full Person struct (so cannot be directly serialized into JSON). In the HTML helper, I can transform those property values into a struct, but I don't know how to transform it back into a simple type on POST. The solution I need would transform an ID into a new Person struct on page load, serializing it into the hidden field. On POST, it would deserialize the generated JSON back into a simple array of IDs.

Is a custom model binder the solution I need? How can I tell it to work both with a custom model AND simple types (because I don't want it applied to EVERY string property, just need it to deal with the values given by the HTML helper).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, it's possible!

To clarify, I needed to: transform a string or string array (of IDs) into a JSON structure for my hidden field value, then on post back, deserialize the JSON in the hidden field and transform the struct back into a simple string or string array (of IDs) for my domain object's property.

### Step 1: Create a HTML helper

I had done this already, but only for accepting my custom AutoCompleteModel type. I needed one for a string and an Enumerable of string type.

All I did was generate my Person struct(s) from the value of the property and serialize them into JSON for the hidden field the Autocompleter uses (this is an example of the `string` helper, I also have a nearly identical one for `IEnumerable<string>`):

```
public static MvcHtmlString AutoComplete<TModel>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, string>> idProp)
    where TModel : class
{
    TModel model = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model;
    string id = idProp.Compile().Invoke(model);

    string propertyName = idProp.GetPropertyName();

    Person[] people = new Person[] {
        new Person() { ID = id }
    };

    // Don't name the textbox the same name as the property,
    // otherwise the value will be whatever the textbox is,
    // if you care.
    MvcHtmlString textBox = htmlHelper.TextBox(propertyName + "_ac", string.Empty);

    // For me, the JSON is the value I want to postback
    MvcHtmlString hidden = htmlHelper.Hidden(propertyName, new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(people));

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(
        "<span class=\"AutoComplete\">" +
            textBox.ToHtmlString() +
            hidden.ToHtmlString() +
        "</span>");
}
```

Usage: `@Html.AutoComplete(model => model.ID)`

### Step 2: Create a custom model binder

The crux of my issue was that I needed this binder to only apply to certain properties, and they were strings or string arrays.

I was inspired by this [article](http://eliasbland.wordpress.com/2009/08/08/enumeration-model-binder-for-asp-net-mvc/) because it used Generics. I decided, hey, we can just ask people what property they want to apply the binder for.

```
public class AutoCompleteBinder<T> : DefaultModelBinder
    where T : class
{
    private IEnumerable<string> PropertyNames { get; set; }

    public AutoCompleteBinder(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] idProperties)
    {
        this.PropertyNames = idProperties.Select(x => x.GetPropertyName());
    }

    protected override object GetPropertyValue(
        ControllerContext controllerContext, 
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
        PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, 
        IModelBinder propertyBinder)
    {
        var submittedValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (submittedValue != null && this.PropertyNames.Contains(propertyDescriptor.Name))
        {
            string json = submittedValue.AttemptedValue;

            Person[] people = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Person[]>(json);

            if (people != null && people.Any())
            {
                string[] IDs = people.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ID)).Select(x => x.ID).ToArray();

                bool isArray = bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(string) && 
                    (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(string[]) || 
                    bindingContext.ModelType.HasInterface<IEnumerable>());

                if (IDs.Count() == 1 && !isArray)
                    return IDs.First(); // return string
                else if (IDs.Count() > 0 && isArray)
                    return IDs.ToArray(); // return string[]
                else
                    return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        return base.GetPropertyValue(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, propertyBinder);
    }
}
```

`GetPropertyName()` (translate LINQ expression into a string, i.e. `m => m.ID` = `ID`) and `HasInterface()` are just two utility methods I have.

### Step 3: Register

Register the binder on your domain objects and their properties in `Application_Start`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Employee), new AutoCompleteBinder<Employee>(e => e.ID, e => e.TeamIDs));
```

It's only a little bit annoying to have to register the binder for specific properties, but it's not the end of the world and provides a nice, smooth experience working with my autocompleter.

Any comments are welcome.